# Switch to new installed Perl Version for migrating otrs config files on CentOS 6

Tags: perl, centos, otrs, perlbrew

I'll start from the beginning:

Case: I have to update from an OTRS 5 (already in use for years) to OTRS 6.

I followed [Update from OTRS 5 to OTRS 6](https://doc.otrs.com/doc/manual/admin/6.0/en/html/updating.html) of the OTRS Docs.

I did everything as described until it comes to [converting the XML configuration files](http://doc.otrs.com/doc/manual/developer/6.0/en/html/package-porting.html#packge-porting-5-to-6-configuration-files). Therefor I need Perl.

The default installed Perl version is 5.10.*. For converting those XML, I need at least 5.16.*.

I installed Perl-5.20.* manually by downloading the .gz and following installation instructions.

Command 'perl -v' still shows `perl-5.10`.

I googled how to switch between several Perl versions and found "perlbrew". I installed it. I used the command: `perlbrew list`. This should show me all installed perls. It didn't show me nothing. So I installed Perl v.5.26.* via Perlbrew and switched to it. It seemed to work.

Using command `perl -v` still shows me `Perl-5.10.*`.

I read through the whole internet.
I however can't switch to a new Perl version, so I can't convert those XMLs. Because the Migration Script still tells me, there is Perl 5.10 installed and at least 5.16 needed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you manually compile a Perl, you need to specifically use it. `perl` on the command line will use whatever is in your `PATH`. That's probably the system Perl. Perlbrew doesn't know about the Perls you've compiled yourself outside of it. It only sees the system Perl and its own Perls. How did you _switch_ to your 5.26?

Comment: Where did you see that you require a Perl 5.16? Does the migration helper script explicitly say that?

Comment: `perlbrew` is a good approach. What is the result when you say `perlbrew use perl-5.26.2` and then immediately after `which perl` and `perl -v`?

Comment: @simbabque Oh, okay. I switched to 5.26 using command "perlbrew switch perl-5.26.2. Yes, the OTRS Migration Tool explicitly asks for perl v5.16.

Comment: @haukex In all cases it returns perl-5.26.2. But when I try to use that migration tool, it still returns that I´m using perl-5.10.

Comment: @haukex https://i.stack.imgur.com/qw3WS.png

Answer (score 0):

The shebang line of [`otrs.Console.pl`](https://github.com/OTRS/otrs/blob/master/bin/otrs.Console.pl) is `#!/usr/bin/perl`, which means that when you run it from the command line as `bin/otrs.Console.pl`, it will use `/usr/bin/perl`, regardless of what other `perl`s you have installed.

Either run the command as `perl bin/otrs.Console.pl ...`, or change the first line of `otrs.Console.pl` into `#!/usr/bin/env perl`.

*Edit* as per the discussion in the comments: You needed to run the command as the `otrs` user, and you were trying to do so via `su otrs ...`. The issue with that is that `perlbrew` will by default install its `perl`s only for the current user. So you need to *first* log in as the `otrs` user, *then* use `perlbrew` to install and switch to a newer Perl, and then apply one of the solutions I suggested above.

Comment: After changing the first line as proposed and installing all necessary modules (DateTime and DBI) I get following error: bin/otrs.Console.pl: line 21, 22 and 24: use: command not found    
 line 25: syntax error near unexpected token `('     line 25:`use FindBin qw($RealBin);'

Comment: @user9696859 Did you try just running the command as `perl bin/otrs.Console.pl ...`? In [the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOK14.png) (from your proposed edit - you should have posted it as a comment instead) you seem to be running the command with `su otrs bin/otrs.Console.pl`, which was not my suggestion.

Comment: @user9696859 The same way you did [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020799/switch-to-new-installed-perl-version-for-migrating-otrs-config-files-on-centos-6/50074649#comment87141462_50020799).

Comment: I also tried it with: su otrs perl bin/otrs.Console.pl the console returns: "/usr/bin/perl: /usr/bin/perl: cannot execute binary file" Sorry, entweder stelle ich mich zu dumm an oder iwas stimmt nicht... Danke für deine Geduld

Comment: @user9696859 Try it *without* the `su otrs`, *just* `perl bin/otrs.Console.pl ...` (Ich hoffe, damit klappt's.) - or at least without the `orts`, you might need `su` (but be careful with that).

Comment: If I try it with the root user, it tells me to run it with the otrs User, which is "otrs". That´s why I tried it with "su otrs". Without "otrs" it tells me, that the user perl doesn´t exist -.-

Comment: How do I use "su" in this case? Isn´t it used to "use" a different user? I don´t get it...

Comment: Now I logged on as the otrs user. The first line of otrs.Console.pl is changed to ´#!/usr/bin/env perl´. It still tells me, that perl v.5.16.0 is required and that only perl v5.10.1 is installed...

Comment: Ah, now I think I see more clearly what's going on. Note that `perlbrew` only installs Perl for the current user. 1. Log in as the `otrs` user. 2. Use `perlbrew` to install a newer Perl. 3. Try running `perl bin/otrs.Console.pl ...` (without `su`).

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped to solve my problem. Everything worked out fine! Du hast mich gerettet! :)

Comment: @user9696859 Glad to help! I've edited the answer to include the extra information.

Comment: Thank you again! :)